# Как передать imageBlob, если он вложен внутрь массива? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Часто делают такую передачу файла на сервер:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}

let formData = new FormData()

formData.append('data', this.data)
for (var i = 0; i < this.numberOfFiles; i++) {
    formData.append('file[' + i + ']', this.file[i])
}

this.$http.post(`/save`, formData, config)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

То есть идёт отдельно: данные и медиа-данные.
В моём же случае, у меня файлы находятся внутри переменной `this.data`. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
let data = [
    {
        text: '...',
        text2: '...',
        date: '10.02.12',
        files: [
            File(),
            File()
        ]
    },
    {
        text: '...',
        text2: '...',
        date: '10.02.12',
        files: [
            File(),
            File(),
            File(),
            File()
        ]
    },
    {
        text: '...',
        text2: '...',
        date: '10.02.12',
        files: [
            File(),
            File(),
            File(),
            File(),
            File()
        ]
    },
]
```

Как вложить этот самый imageBlob, чтобы данные можно было передать сразу так `formData.append('data', this.data)` а не вот так `formData.append('file[' + i + ']', this.file[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
data.forEach(item => {
    Array.from(item.files).forEach((file, index) => {
        formData.append(`media[${item.id}][${index}]`, file)
    })
})
```

А на сервере принимаем так (если PHP\Laravel):

```
$files = $request->file('media')[$item->id];

foreach($files as $file){
    $filename = uniqid() . '-' . str_replace(' ', '_', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $path = Storage::putFileAs('public/files', $file, $filename);
}
```

То есть в этом массиве у объектов должен быть какой-то уникальный ключ для определения.

Comment: Правда это всё с тем же `formData.append('media', file)`, но с многоходовочкой